# Open api generator spring - generic return type with multiple successful http status codes

Tags: openapi-generator

We have a service that needs can return different HTTP status codes (200 or 202) dependent on the underlying service layer. However, when we generate the code using open api generator for spring version 6.4.0 the return type in the interface only points to the type (object/schema) for the 200 response. We have two different schemas dependent on the HTTP status code:

Example schema:

```
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Http status 200 response
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              data:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/ModelA"
    "202":
      description: Http status 202 response
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              data:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/ModelB"`
```

The generated interface looks like this:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-03-14T11:43:14.958518400+01:00[Europe/Berlin]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "someServiceName", description = "service discription")
public interface SomeServiceApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    
    @Operation(
            operationId = "call1ed13777Ddc64343884b37b50b3b0cc1",
            summary = "Some API",
            description = "",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Http status 200 response", content = {
                            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Model1ed13777Ddc64343884b37b50b3b0cc1200Response.class))
                    }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "Http status 202 response", content = {
                            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Model1ed13777Ddc64343884b37b50b3b0cc1202Response.class))
                    })
            }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            value = "/someRandomEndpoint",
            produces = { "application/json" },
            consumes = { "application/json" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<ModelA> call1ed13777Ddc64343884b37b50b3b0cc1(
    ) throws Exception {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"data\" : \"\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

How do we get the open API generator to use a generic return type like "Object", Interface or Abstract class, etc. instead of the concreate "ModelA" return type?

We tried to generate with the config option "responseWrapper" from https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/, but this wrapps the whole ResponseEntity

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across your question.
I had a similar problem in a project recently. I guess you solved your problem after one year, but for the next one finding this, I thought it would be useful to have an answer at hand.

OpenApi supports discriminator objects, which is pretty much exactly what you want. This is from the official openapi specification doc:

```
MyResponseType:
  oneOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: petType
```

This is basically saying, that your `ResponseType` needs to match one of the listed schemas, `Cat`, `Dog` or `Lizard` and its determined by the `petType` discriminator.

There is more to it, but I would suggest reading the openapi specification to understand the full concept.
Hope this helps!